# setear un value en ReactSelect sin usar onChange

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Tengo un componente ReactSelect donde al seleccionar una opcion el "onChange" almacena como "client_id" el value del option, hasta ahi todo funciona ok, el tema es cuando traigo un dato preseleccionado por el usuario y lo seteo en la ubicacion [0] (por eso es el value por default), al no utilizar el "onChange" del componente no se setea con el formato que necesito.

Hay alguna forma de ejecutar el onChange o de setear el value con el formato automaticamente, sin que se seleccione nada en el select?

Ahora lo que me devuelve es el initialValues que tiene cargado el Formik y no el formato que se genera cuando se selecciona el cliente desde el select...

Paso como tengo el componente

````
/*este es el uso que realizo con el value almacenado*/
const handleNewDate = async (values) => {
        const data = {
            title: values.title,
            client_id: values.client_id,            
        };
        console.log(data);
        console.log(values);        
    };

<Formik
 initialValues={initialValues}
 onSubmit={(values) => handleNewDate(values)}>
 {({ values, handleChange, handleSubmit }) => (

/*select que tiene precargado en la opcion 0 lo que necesito en el value pero que no se carga con el formato value.client_id lo que nunca se ejecuta el onChange*/
  <ReactSelect
    options={clientsOptions}
    placeholder="Seleccione el cliente"
    value={clientsOptions[0]}
    defaultValue={clientsOptions[0]}
     onChange={(value) => {
       handleChange({
         target: {
             name: "client_id",
             value: value.value,
         },
       });
       handleClientChange(value);
       }}
    menuPortalTarget={document.body}
    styles={{
         menuPortal: (base) => ({ ...base, zIndex: 9999 }),
    }}
 )}

</Formik>
 /> ```
````

Comment: debes setear el initial values no en la posicion x([x]) sino que initialvalues deberia ser un estado en tu componente, y cuando tengas data por ejemplo en un update debes seteral intialvalues